# error at the end of python3-pydantic for grapejuice depends not installable

Tags: apt, python3

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
grapejuice : Depends: python3 (>= 3.7~) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
Depends: python3-pydantic but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Does anyone know how to fix this for me please?

Comment: in this  case mines is the newest but nothing change

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @ArturMeinild Actually it isn't the correct answer as you can verify from JACOB Mondejar's comment under my answer. Please retract your closed vote.

Comment: Well do you know how to solve

Answer (score 1):

The python3-pydantic package is in the universe repository in
Ubuntu 20.04 and later. Install the python3-pydantic package from Ubuntu 20.04 in Ubuntu 18.04 with the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pydantic/python3-pydantic_1.2-1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./python3-pydantic_1.2-1_all.deb
```

Comment: @JACOBMondejar If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Comment: I found out the problem. Python3-Pydantic is only in Ubuntu 20.04 but not for Ubuntu 18.04 and lower. That's how I got the error. How can it be available if not listed for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: python3-pydantic is not available directly from the repositories of 18.04, so you need to **manually download** it with `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pydantic/python3-pydantic_1.2-1_all.deb` I know it's from the 20.04 repositories, but it works in 18.04 too, so manually download it anyway.